# Max-width in HTML?

Tags: html, ios, iphone, email

I'm trying to create a email signature that consists of a banner image, and three clickable areas for social media icons.

I was having an issue with the scaling the banner and not working correctly, but after resolving that I'm now having an issue with trying to set the "max-width".

```html
<a href="http://xbox.com/"><!--CHANGE THIS URL FOR EACH IMAGE!--><img src="http://www.thegamescabin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/next-xbox-logo-5.png" width="100%" alt="Xbox" max-width="600px"/>
```

The image resizes to the device (WHICH IS PERFECT) however, I'm struggling to get it to have a "max-width" of 600px.

Answer (score 0):

`max-width` is a CSS attribute, not a HTML one (your `max-width=""` doesn't exist and is thus ignored), so you'll want to use a `style` attribute:

`<a href="http://xbox.com/"><!--CHANGE THIS URL FOR EACH IMAGE!--><img src="http://www.thegamescabin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/next-xbox-logo-5.png" width="100%" alt="Xbox" style="max-width:600px;"/>`

Comment: Didn't seem to work, still ignoring the "style=", Do I need to place a style at the top, or will this work fine?

Comment: @VivaLaJam26 Do you have a viewport meta tag in the email?

Comment: I haven't. How (and where) do I put this? As you maybe able to tell, I'm very new to coding and using HTMl.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this.

```
<a href="http://xbox.com/"><!--CHANGE THIS URL FOR EACH IMAGE!--><img src="http://www.thegamescabin.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/next-xbox-logo-5.png" width="600px" alt="Xbox""/></a>
```

and in css

```
img{max-width:100%}
```

Comment: CSS that isn't in a `style` attribute is often problematic in email.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to avoid CSS for email sigs as I know there can be an issue with them.